# When a button is clicked, how do I show an element if another element contains a specific text?

Tags: html, jquery, css, hide, show

When I click on the button, I want the `#test2` element to show if `span.test1` contains the keyword 'TEST'. I'm new with jquery so I'm not sure what I need to change here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function()           
   if ($("span.test1:contains(TEST)") {
              $("#test2").show()
  };
  };
```

```css
#test2 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
<span class="test1">TEST</span>
<div id="test2">TEST2</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: You missed some open close curly braces and brackets. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as shown below. I used the `is()` method so that we can cache reference to the element and test `:contains` selector against it.

Otherwise the selectors inside click handler will be looked up on each click.

```js
const $test1 = $("span.test1");
const $test2 = $("#test2");
$("#button").click(function() {
  if ($test1.is(':contains("TEST")')) {
    $test2.show()
  };
});
```

```css
#test2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
<span class="test1">TEST</span>
<div id="test2">TEST2</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RegExp to check if the string contains a specific word or not.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var txt = $("span.test1").text();
  if (/test/i.test(txt)) // "i" is for case case-insensitive
    $("#test2").show()
});
```

```css
#test2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
<span class="test1">this is a sample TEST</span>
<div id="test2">TEST2</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
      if(document.getElementById("test1").innerText.includes("TEST")){
      $('#test2').html("yes it includes")
      console.log("yes")
    }
    })
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
  <span id="test1">TEST</span>
  <div id="test2"></div>
```

Comment: Please include jQuery lib on the snippet. Currently, it's  throw error.